# Geb test use method from across multiple setup files

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I have multiple methods scattered in multiple spec files and would like to use them in one test. How do I call the method from another spec file? Is it possible to extend multiple spec files?

```
class MyTestSpec extends Page1Spec {

    def 'first part of test"() {

        Page2Spec.methodInPage2Spec() // TRYING TO USE METHOD IN ANOTHER FILE
        Page3Spec.methodInPage3Spec() // Trying to use method in another file

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using traits if you have methods you want to use across multiple specs:

For example, a sign in trait:

```
trait SignInTrait  {

    MyPage loginAs(String username, String password) {

        to SignInPage

        //login etc

        browser.at(MyPage)
    }
}
```

Can be added to any spec:

```
class MySpec extends GebReportingSpec implements SignInTrait  {

    def "I can do stuff"(){

        when: "i do stuff"

            //call trait method
            def myPage = loginAs("myname", "mypassword")

        then: "blah"

            //some code
    }
}
```

You can add multiple traits seperated by a comma:

```
class MySpec extends GebReportingSpec implements SignInTrait, AnotherTrait
```